# Using offline forms for data entry into google sheets in android

Tags: android, google-forms, google-sheets-api

With the offline option in Google sheets android app, I am able to enter data on a shared sheet and it is synced when I connect to internet.

But instead of directly entering in Google Sheets, is there an app or some other work around available to enter data in a structured manner.

Using google forms, we can do this structured data entry to google sheets. Unfortunately, google forms is not available as offline app for android. Is there any other alternative?

I looked at ODK Collect, but it looked little complicated esp. setting up of Aggregate server. It would be good, if any other app can write data directly to google sheet offline.

Comment: If you're only looking for possible apps, you may try the apps listed in [Zapier's article](https://zapier.com/learn/ultimate-guide-to-forms-and-surveys/best-data-collection-apps/) and see if it addresses your needs. Based from the article, with these apps, you'll be able to collect data on a mobile device even if you're offline.

Answer (score -1):

**Formotus** recently announced [support for Google Sheets](http://www.formotus.com/20532/blog-news/business-forms-mobile-apps-google-drive-sheets) and Google Drive. Formotus forms run in mobile apps (iOS/Android/Windows) that are optimized for offline data collection, and now can submit data to Sheets and PDF to Drive. You can check it out with a free trial.

-Glen